# Altering the menu items of camera

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

I am invoking camera from my application. i want to remove few menu items that is provided by the camera application. how to do that.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove menu items from native apps like Camera or Calendar.
You can only add menu items to [some of them](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11935/Create_a_menu_item_602617_11.jsp) , but you [can't add menu item to Camera](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Add-MenuItem-to-Camera-Application/m-p/28393) neither.